# Android Drop Shadow similar to Google Play's Music Now Playing

Tags: android

I am trying to achieve this dropshadow that is on the top of the Now Playing in Google Play Music.

[image]
.

I have tried to use various dropshadows from outside sources and Android's resources like, but have not been able to get this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `LOLLIPOP` you could set the `elevation` attribute of the "Now Playing" box and the shadow should appear (try values of `4dp` or `8dp` if that was not enough).

On lower versions I would wrap the "Now Playing" box in a vertical `LinearLayout`. The **second** child would be the "Now Playing" box. The **first** child would be a shadow view such as this one:

```
<View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="8dp"
  android:background="@drawable/shadow_upwards"/>
```

**shadow_upwards.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:angle="90"
      android:startColor="#40000000"
      android:endColor="#00000000"/>
</shape>
```

Right now I'm not sure about the optimal alpha value of `startColor`. It will definitely be between `20` and `66`.

Comment: This approach works but how would I get the shadow to overlap the element behind it so the views below are shown through the shadow instead of just appearing?

Edit: I'm talking about scrollable views.

Comment: You could use a `RelativeLayout`. The bottom box would be defined last so it's drawn on top. The content view should have margin of the same size as the height of the bottom box. That way there's no content behind the bottom box but the shadow still overlays it.